# How to enlarge a circle?

Tags: geometry, transformation

if you are given a circle with equation $(x-a)^2 + (y-b^2) = r^2$ and it is enlarged by a factor of $3$ what would the new equation be?

Would you put $2x$ an $2y$ in the place of $y$?

Comment: enlarged through the origin*

Comment: Enlarged how?  By area?  Then replace $r^2$ with $3 r^2$.  By diameter?  Then replace $r^2$ by $9 r^2$.

Comment: Note that if e.g. $(7,5)$ is on the circle, you want $(21,15)$ on the new circle, so it's a *third* the $x$- and $y$-values that fulfill the old equation, not a (larger) multiple.

Answer (score 3):

To scale through a center by factor $\lambda$ use:

$$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = (\lambda r)^2$$

and to scale through the origin use:

$$\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}-a\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y}{\lambda}-b\right)^2 = r^2.$$

Blue is the original, violet was scaled through the origin and green through the center.

[image: circles]

Picture courtesy by [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-1%29%5E2%2B%28y-1%29%5E2%3D1%2C+%28x%2F3-1%29%5E2%2B%28y%2F3-1%29%5E2%3D1%2C+%28x-1%29%5E2%2B%28y-1%29%5E2%3D9).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply r alone by 3 in the equation, it means you are leaving circle center location unaltered with respect to origin, magnifying size of circle only. Draw lines parallel to x- and y-axes to see this.

However if you are multiplying r,a and b by 3, it means you are making a similar circle shifted radially out. You can view it as magnified with respect to origin as vertex of similarity between two tangents. Draw tangents to circles from origin to see this.